# GraphQL build issue: Interface 'ExecutionResult<TData>' incorrectly extends interface 'ExecutionResult'

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I am building a GraphQL lambda server with typescript@4.9.4 graphql@15.8.0 apollo-server-lambda@2.19.0, but got the following error:

```
node_modules/apollo-link/lib/types.d.ts(5,18): error TS2430: Interface 'ExecutionResult<TData>' incorrectly extends interface 'ExecutionResult<{ [key: string]: any; }, { [key: string]: any; }>'
Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
  Type 'TData | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; } | null | undefined'.
    Type 'TData' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; } | null | undefined'.
      Type 'TData' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Have tried to install different graphql versions ^14.0.0 ^16.0.0? They did not work.

package.json dependencies:

```
    "@aws-sdk/client-kms": "^3.16.0",
    "apollo-server-lambda": "2.19.0",
    "aws-embedded-metrics": "^2.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "axios-retry": "^3.2.5",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
```